# CUP Error "Couldn't repair and continue parse"

Tags: java, parsing, lex, jflex, cup

Working on CUP. Here are my files:
A3.cup:

```
import java.io.*;
import java_cup.runtime.*;
/* Terminals (tokens returned by the scanner). */
terminal         TIMES, DIVIDE, OPAREN, CPAREN, BEGIN, END, RETURN, IF, ELSE, WRITE, READ, MAIN, Id, NEQUALTO, EQUALTO, Num, PLUS, MINUS, INT, REAL, STRING, ASSIGN, SEMI, COM, QString;

/* Non terminals */
non terminal MatchedStmt, UnmatchedStmt, OtherStmt, Stmt,  Program, MethodDecl, Block, Type, FormalParams, FormalParam, LocalVarDecl, AssignStmt;
non terminal ReturnStmt, WriteStmt, ReadStmt, Expression, MultiplicativeExpr, PrimaryExpr, BoolExpression, ActualParams;
non terminal NonEmptyActualParams, StatementList, NonEmptyFormalParams;
/* Precedences */
precedence left PLUS, MINUS;
precedence left TIMES, DIVIDE;


/* The grammar */
Program ::= Program MethodDecl
        | MethodDecl
        ;
        
Type ::= INT | REAL | STRING;
MethodDecl ::= Type MAIN Id OPAREN FormalParams CPAREN Block
             | Type Id OPAREN FormalParams CPAREN Block
                ;
FormalParams ::= /* empty */
              | NonEmptyFormalParams
              ;
NonEmptyFormalParams ::= FormalParam
                      | NonEmptyFormalParams COM FormalParam
                      ;

FormalParam ::= Type Id;

Block ::= BEGIN StatementList END;

StatementList ::= /* empty */
                | StatementList Stmt
               ;


Stmt ::= MatchedStmt
      | UnmatchedStmt
;

MatchedStmt ::= IF OPAREN BoolExpression CPAREN MatchedStmt ELSE MatchedStmt
             | OtherStmt
             ;

UnmatchedStmt ::= IF OPAREN BoolExpression CPAREN Stmt
                | IF OPAREN BoolExpression CPAREN MatchedStmt ELSE UnmatchedStmt
                ;

OtherStmt ::= Block
        | LocalVarDecl
        | AssignStmt
        | ReturnStmt
        | WriteStmt
        | ReadStmt      
;

LocalVarDecl ::= Type Id SEMI | Type AssignStmt;
AssignStmt ::= Id ASSIGN Expression SEMI
             | Id ASSIGN QString SEMI
             ;
ReturnStmt ::= RETURN Expression SEMI;

WriteStmt ::= WRITE OPAREN Expression COM QString CPAREN SEMI;

ReadStmt ::= READ OPAREN Expression COM QString CPAREN SEMI;
Expression ::= MultiplicativeExpr
            | Expression PLUS MultiplicativeExpr
            | Expression MINUS MultiplicativeExpr       
            ;
MultiplicativeExpr ::= PrimaryExpr
                    | MultiplicativeExpr TIMES PrimaryExpr
                    | MultiplicativeExpr DIVIDE PrimaryExpr
                    ;

PrimaryExpr ::= Num
              | Id
              | OPAREN Expression CPAREN
              | Id OPAREN ActualParams CPAREN
              ;
BoolExpression ::= Expression EQUALTO Expression
                 | Expression NEQUALTO Expression
                 ;
ActualParams ::= /* empty */
              | NonEmptyActualParams
              ;
NonEmptyActualParams ::= Expression
                      | NonEmptyActualParams COM Expression
                      ;
```

A3.lex:

```
import java_cup.runtime.*;
%%

%implements java_cup.runtime.Scanner
%type Symbol
%function next_token
%class A3Scanner
%eofval{ return null;
%eofval}
%state COMMENT


KEYWORDS = (WRITE|READ|IF|ELSE|RETURN|STRING|BEGIN|END|MAIN|INT|REAL)
Id = [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*
Num = [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?

%%
<YYINITIAL> "/**" { yybegin(COMMENT); }
<YYINITIAL>"+" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.PLUS); }
<YYINITIAL>"-" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.MINUS); }
<YYINITIAL>"*" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.TIMES); }
<YYINITIAL>"/" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.DIVIDE); }
<YYINITIAL>"MAIN" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.MAIN); }
<YYINITIAL>"BEGIN" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.BEGIN); }
<YYINITIAL>"END" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.END); }
<YYINITIAL>"(" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.OPAREN); }
<YYINITIAL>")" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.CPAREN); }
<YYINITIAL>";" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.SEMI); }
<YYINITIAL>{Id} { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.Id); }
<YYINITIAL>{Num} { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.Num); }
<YYINITIAL> "RETURN" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.RETURN); }
<YYINITIAL> "IF" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.IF); }
<YYINITIAL> "ELSE" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.ELSE); }
<YYINITIAL> "WRITE" {  return new Symbol(A3Symbol.WRITE); }
<YYINITIAL> "READ" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.READ); }
<YYINITIAL> "!=" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.NEQUALTO); }
<YYINITIAL> "==" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.EQUALTO); }
<YYINITIAL> "INT" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.INT); }
<YYINITIAL> "REAL" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.REAL); }
<YYINITIAL> "STRING" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.STRING); }
<YYINITIAL> "=" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.ASSIGN); }
<YYINITIAL> "," { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.COM); }
<YYINITIAL> "\"[^\"]\"" { return new Symbol(A3Symbol.QString); }
<YYINITIAL>.|\n|\r {}

<COMMENT> "**/" { yybegin(YYINITIAL); }
<COMMENT>. {}
<COMMENT>\n|\r {}


\r|\n {}
. {}
```

A3User.java:

```
import java.io.*; class A3User {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File inputFile = new File ("A3.tiny");
        A3Parser parser= new A3Parser(new A3Scanner(new FileInputStream(inputFile)));
         Integer result =(Integer)parser.parse().value;
        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(new File("A3.output"));
        fw.write("Number of methods: "+ result.intValue());
        fw.close();
    } }
```

The Output file should contain:

```
Number of methods: #
```

It is not creating the output file and I am not sure why.
Using this input:
A3.tiny

```
/** sahftrjhesj ew**
**/
INT f(INT x, INT y )
BEGIN
    z:=x;
    z := x*x - y*y;
    RETURN x+z;
END

INT MAIN f1()
BEGIN
    REAL x;
    READ(x, "A41.input");
    REAL y;
    READ(y, "A42.input");
    INT z;

    z:=0;
    IF (x!=y) z := f2(x,y) + f2(y,x);
    WRITE (z, "A4.output");
 END
```

It should create:
A3.output:

```
Number of methods: 2
```

Instead, it gives me the following error even though everything else compiled correctly:

```
Processing first section -- user code.
Processing second section -- JLex declarations.
Processing third section -- lexical rules.
Creating NFA machine representation.
NFA comprised of 173 states.
Working on character classes.::.::..:::::::....::::::.:.:.::...:.::.:........::................::::.:.:::..........
NFA has 36 distinct character classes.
Creating DFA transition table.
Working on DFA states..............................................................................
Minimizing DFA transition table.
64 states after removal of redundant states.
Outputting lexical analyzer code.
Opening files...
Parsing specification from standard input...
Checking specification...
Building parse tables...
  Computing non-terminal nullability...
  Computing first sets...
  Building state machine...
  Filling in tables...
  Checking for non-reduced productions...
Writing parser...
Closing files...
------- CUP v0.10k Parser Generation Summary -------
  0 errors and 0 warnings
  27 terminals, 24 non-terminals, and 51 productions declared, 
  producing 102 unique parse states.
  0 terminals declared but not used.
  0 non-terminals declared but not used.
  0 productions never reduced.
  0 conflicts detected (0 expected).
  Code written to "A3Parser.java", and "A3Symbol.java".
---------------------------------------------------- (v0.10k)
Syntax error
Couldn't repair and continue parse
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Can't recover from previous error(s)
    at java_cup.runtime.lr_parser.report_fatal_error(lr_parser.java:361)
    at java_cup.runtime.lr_parser.unrecovered_syntax_error(lr_parser.java:409)
    at java_cup.runtime.lr_parser.parse(lr_parser.java:601)
    at A3User.main(A3User.java:5)
```

Let me know if you see anything I need to fix.